# Define a property for a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

Is such declaration of getter and setter for a property correct and most efficient?

```
var AxisRange = (function(){
    function AxisRange(){
        this._userMaxValue = 0.0;

        Object.defineProperty(AxisRange.prototype, "UserMaxValue", {
            get : function(){
                return this._userMaxValue;
            },
            set  : function(value){
                if(value != this._userMaxValue){
                    this._userMaxValue = value;
                    this.validateUserMaxValue();
                    this.validateUserStep();

                    this.synchronizeActualRange();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    AxisRange.prototype.validateUserMaxValue = function(){
        alert("validateUserMaxValue");
    };

    return AxisRange;
})();
```

Also, I'm using JetBrains WebStorm to write my JS code, and it warns me that

1. `AxisRange.prototype`  used in `Object.defineProperty` is not assignable to parameter  type Object.
2. in line `if(value != this._userMaxValue)` is says "Possible invalid usage of this."

Before I go any further with code typing I need to make sure what I'm using is correct.

Comment: You should move the `Object.defineProperty` call outside the constructor function, but apart from this it looks fine.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp helps with how to define objects, properties, and methods

Comment: and I agree with Felix, the getter/setter functions should be on the same level as the validateUserMaxValue

Comment: Or, if `_userMaxValue` is intended to be "*private*," you can declare it as a scoped variable with `var` rather than `this.` and define the property on `this` rather than the `prototype`.

Comment: I did all the suggestions above, only when I replace `prototype` with `this` , the setter is not called, thus I don't get the alert from validateUserMaxValue. If I use `prototype` then all works as needed. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You're defining a prototype property inside the constructor. That means it will be re-defined every time you make a new AxisRange object. Move that out of the constructor function.

You also might want to get rid of that closure, because you're not using it to namespace any local variables and it will complicate attempts to optimize your JavaScript. (Google Closure Compiler will especially complain if you ever use it.)

Comment: would such a code `http://pastebin.com/fzdUUHD1` be correct? It works as expect though, but I'm still getting a warning when using `AxisRange.prototype` in `Object.defineProperty`. But if I replace it with `this` the setter won't be called.

Comment: It looks fine. I've never used JetBrains WebStorm, so have no idea what it's complaining about. Maybe it wants you to explicitly set the AxisRange variable: var AxisRange = function AxisRange()?